# Flat non-concrete subsurface for outdoor rubber tile

Tags: leveling

I have a 10' x 7'6" area of dirt over which I have installed 20"x20" 3/4"-thick rubber tile ([Rubber-Cal Eco-Sport](http://www.rubbercal.com/eco-sport-3-4-inch-interlocking-rubber-flooring-tiles.html)). The tiles are connected using inter-tile plastic pins-- there is no adhesive. I use the surface as an outdoor workout area.

The area was not at all level before tile installation, and I put a lot of effort into getting it as flat as I could using a hand-tamper and landscape rake. The result is OK, but definitely not as flat as I would like. I would like to remove the tile, flatten the area more, and reinstall it. I would also like to avoid pouring concrete.

I am unsure of the best way to proceed, since towards the end of my previous effort to level the dirt I was getting diminishing returns. It seemed very difficult to achieve a very flat plane on soil alone (this soil is somewhat clay-like). I am wondering whether if it might make sense to put in a few inches of a granular subsurface underneath my tile.

I have no experience with this sort of thing, so have been relying purely on internet research. I see many videos of people installing stone patio pavers over sand, but it's not clear to me *why* exactly this subsurface is used and whether it would be appropriate for my use case. As I said, I use the area for workouts so there is a good deal of impact and moving around on the surface. I am concerned that a granular subsurface might develop "dents" over time from, say, dropping a heavy weight.

**What would be a good way to achieve a flatter subsurface for my tile? Should I put sand/gravel over the dirt? If so, how much should I use?**

Comment: Stone dust may help.Makes a nice solid base.  Add a few inches rake it out,wet it compact it.  Would due at least 4 to 5 inches.

Answer (score 2):

I have horses, we put down at least 4” of crushed quarry  or shale rock then use a plate compactor while watering it any low spots are filled and we get the areas quite flat then 3/4 rubber mats are put down. This usually holds up for about 5 years with even draft horses standing in the same spot (at the door with there head out) for hours a day our big boy weighs in at 1500+

If ours can hold up to this abuse it should be able to a person, a plate compactor will do a much better job than trying to do it by hand, add water and it really locks the crushed rock fines together. Note a compactor can be rented, also never use crushed river rock as it has partially round edges and never locks together like shale or crushed quarry will.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all top soil, compact area.  Use stone dust,wet and compact every 2 inches. About 6 inches thick. Makes solid base,driveways done this way.And snow plows go on them . You could use two pvc pipes on the ground,add fill screed with a 2x4 to level off.  Or wet it down and see were it has low spots .